# SQL Stored Queries - use result of query as boolean based on existence of records

Tags: sql, mysql, nested, conditional-statements

Just getting into SQL stored queries right now... anyway, here's my database schema (simplified for YOUR convenience):

`member`
`------`
`id` INT PK

`board`
`------`
`id` INT PK

`officer`
`------`
`id` INT PK

If you're into OOP, Officer Inherits Board Inherits Member. In other words, if someone is listed on the `officer` table, s/he is listed on the `board` table and the `member` table. I want to find out the highest privilege level someone has. So far my SP looks like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAuthLevel(IN targetID MEDIUMINT)
    BEGIN
        IF 
            SELECT `id`
            FROM `member`
            WHERE `id` = targetID;
        THEN
            IF
                SELECT `id`
                FROM `board`
                WHERE `id` = targetID;
            THEN
                IF
                    SELECT `id`
                    FROM `officer`
                    WHERE `id` = targetID;
                THEN
                    RETURN 3; /*officer*/
                ELSE
                    RETURN 2; /*board member*/
            ELSE
                RETURN 1; /*general member*/
        ELSE
            RETURN 0; /*not a member*/
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

The exact text of the error is 
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near`

```
    'SELECT id
    FROM member
    WHERE id = targetID;
THEN
    IF
        SEL' at line 4
```

I suspect the issue is in the arguments for the IF blocks. What I want to do is return `true` if the result-set is at least one -- i.e. the `id` was found in the table.

Do any of you guys see anything to do here, or should I reconsider my database design into this:?

`person`
`------`
`id` INT PK
`level` SMALLINT

Comment: If member, board and officer are all privilege levels - they should be contained in a single table.  An auto generated, sequential int value isn't reliable - I have a column in the Priveleges table called "rank" or "weight".  Then you could use aggregates (MIN, MAX specifically)...

Comment: Hmm. Well, they're not *just* privilege levels is the thing. They also have more data, for instance `officer` has a `position` field. I suppose I could just put `NULL` in for board and member, though, or put `position` as another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAuthLevel(IN targetID MEDIUMINT)
    BEGIN

    DECLARE var INT;

    SELECT `id` INTO var
    FROM `member`
    WHERE `id` = targetID;

    IF var IS NOT NULL THEN
        ...
```